# Libgdx CameraController limit area

Tags: libgdx

I'm using a number of input controllers. One to control the camera and one to control buttons that have been placed on a scene.

Ive been trying to work out how to create my own custom controller but so far have been unsuccessful in finding any tutorials on how to do it.

Also i would like to deactivate the camera controller if the touch or gesture is bellow a certain height.

Many thanks in any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a class `CamController implements InputProcessor` (or `extends InputAdapter`).
Then override all the methods you need (i use `touchDown` here as an example) and do the following (Pseudocode!!! Do not copy and paste!!!):

```
protected boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    boolean handled = false;
    if (screenX <= maxX && screenX >= minX && screenY <= maxY && screenY >= minY) {
         // The touch is inside the limits of the camera controller, the controller is activated
         // Move camera to the touchpoint:
         camera.position.set(screenX, screenY);
         camra.update();
         handled = true;
    }
    return handled;
}
```

Create the controller for the button, again the controller implements `InputProcessor` an override the methods.
Next in your `ApplicationListener` or in your `Screen`s `create()` or `show()` method you create an `InputMultiplexer`:

```
InputMultiplexer m = new InputMultiplexer(new CamController(camera, limitX, limitY), new ButtonController);
```

And the you just need to set the `InputMultiplexer` as the active `InputProcessor`.
It's important to use `CamController` as the first one, because it then calls `touchDown`-method for this and only if the `touchDown` returns false it calls `touchDown` for the `ButtonController`.

Hope it helps.